# Is snakemake the right tool to use for handling output mediated workflows

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm new to trying out snakemake (last week or so) in order to handle less of the small details for workflows, previously I have coded up my own specific workflow through python.

I generated a small workflow which among the steps would use Illumina PE reads and ran Kraken against them. I'd then parse the output of the Kraken output to detect the most common species (within a set of allowable) if a species value wasn't provided (running with  snakemake -s test.snake --config R1_reads= R2_reads= species=''.

I have 2 questions.

1. What is the recommended approach given the dynamic output/input?

Currently my strategy for this is to create a temp file which
    contains the detected species and then `cat {input.species}` it into
    other shell commands. This doesn't seem elegant but looking through
    the docs I couldn't quite find an adequate alternative. I noticed
    PersistentDicts would let me pass variables between run: commands
    but I'm unsure if I can use that to load variables into a shell:
    section. I also noticed that wrappers could allow me to handle it
    however from the point I need that variable on I'd be wrapping the
    remainder of my workflow.

2. Is snakemake the right tool if I want to use the species afterwards to run a set of scripts specific to the species (with multiple species specific workflows)?

Right now my impression on how to solve this problem is to have multiple workflow files for the species and have a run with switch which calls the associated species workflow dependant on the species.

Appreciate any insight on these questions.

-Kim

Answer (score 0):

You can mark output as dynamic (e.g. expecting one file per species). Then, Snakemake will determine the downstream DAG of jobs after those files have been generated. See http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-files

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes sense so having the dynamix output then referencing each associated expected output from the species specific ones. I'm guessing from this that sometimes touched temp files are the 'right' way to progress?